# Echando mods y relicencia forzada, ¿está todavía Stack Exchange interesada en cooperar con la comunidad?

Tags: discusión, soporte, moderadores, comunidad

*Esta pregunta es una traducción del original [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) por [amon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229223/amon). Los enlaces incluidos son a material en inglés.*

Estas últimas semanas y días he observado cierto comportamiento errático por parte de Stack Exchange Inc., como ciertos cambios al contenido de la licencia probablemente ilegales y la expulsión de moderadores de comunidad intachables sin explicación alguna excepto [respuestas de copiar y pegar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389908/3618829) (haciendo a muchos creer que se hace sin buenos motivos). Ojalá esos fueran ejemplos de malas decisiones, pero la preocupante alternativa es que Stack Exhange ha abandonado la cooperación con la comunidad.

### Incremento en el ratio de acciones incomprensibles.

Hay una [larga](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513/lets-take-a-look-at-the-interaction-between-staff-and-the-power-users-of-the) [historia](https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f) de Stack Exchange alienando a los miembros más comprometidos de la comunidad (y se que muchos ya se han ido como resultado). Esa forma de enfocar las cosas negligentemente es lamentable, pero no claramente maliciosa. Esto parece haber cambiado, para peor.

El 5 de septiembre Stack Exchange [anunció](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-are-moving-to-cc-by-sa-4-0) sin discusión previa que la licencia de contenido se cambiaba retroactivamente. Pese a que el cambio podría ser deseable, se cuestionó ampliamente como algo ilegal. Llevó [tres meses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333615/will-concerns-regarding-the-move-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-elicit-any-further-dialogue-fro) recibir [alguna respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333912) de Stack Exchange, e incluso eso no abordaba las preocupaciones planteadas por la comunidad.

El 27 de septiembre, Stack Exchange expulsó a la moderadora de comunidad Monica Cellio de todos los sitios por ... no estoy realmente seguro del porqué, dado que no soy un mod, pero parece haber sido por un desacuerdo no relacionado. Quitar privilegios de moderador no es una respuesta proporcionada a desacuerdos y [está](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-stealing-content-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooperat?noredirect=1#comment1090600_333968) [en contra](http://web.archive.org/web/20190930175245/https:/twitter.com/tinkertim/status/1053114597014671360) de los principios de Stack Exchange. Esto es extremadamente preocupante: ¿ya no se permite estar en desacuerdo? ¿Ahora Stack Exchange pide lealtad inquebrantable de los moderadores de comunidad? Realmente extraño, pues a Monica se la ha conocido por ser una prolífica y razonable moderadora.

Hasta donde sé, los siguientes moderadores han sido expulsados o han tomado acción en protesta por la expulsión.

1. expulsada: [**Monica Cellio** en Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel) (y otros sitios como The Workplace), proporciona antecedentes.
2. renuncia: [**Gilles** de Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/i-am-resigning-as-a-moderator), [French](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/d%C3%A9mission-de-mon-poste-de-mod%C3%A9rateur), y [Emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/i-am-resigning-as-a-moderator), proporciona antecedentes.
3. <s>renuncia: [**Snow** de The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/resigning-as-moderator)</s>  (posteriormente [pidió ser reinstaurado](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51967323#51967323), [reinstauración confirmada por SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51978502#51978502)) - Ahora aparece como "**decepcionado**"
4. renuncia: [**Jane S** de The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6316/resigning-as-moderator-from-workplace-se)
5. renuncia: [**Dennis** de Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/im-stepping-down)
6. renuncia: [**Caleb** de Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/30) y [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3621/36)
7. renuncia: [**Robert Harvey** de Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/moderator-resignation-notice) y [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/moderator-resignation-notice), más tarde también tuvo su cuenta suspendida.
8. renuncia: [**GlenH7** de Engineering](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/605/moderator-resignation) y [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9001/53019) (luego dejó estos sitios por completo eliminando su cuenta)
9. renuncia: [**Nathaniel** de Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/resigning-as-moderator) y [Latin Language](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421).
10. abandona (¿renuncia?): [**Brock Adams** también conocido como **Awesome Poodles** de Stack Apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333972/)
11. renuncia: [**anonymous2** de Internet of Things](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/goodbye-world-resignation-notice)
12. <s>renuncia: [**Mister Positive** de The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6331/resigning-as-moderator-from-twp)</s> (posteriormente [pidió ser reinstaurado](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51973327#51973327), [reinstauración confirmada por SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51978502#51978502]))
13. renuncia: [**Ed Cottrell** de Stack Overflow y Ebooks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389991/why-i-resigned-as-a-moderator)
14. renuncia: [**DoMiNeLa10** de Emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/im-resigning-from-moderating-on-stack-exchange) **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Emacs)**
15. renuncia: [**a CVn** de Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/moderator-resignation) y [Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/moderator-resignation)
16. renuncia: [**Neil Fein** de Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/resigning-as-a-mod-effective-immediately) **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Writing)**
17. renuncia: [**Glen_b** de Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5765)
18. renuncia: [**Seth** de Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18829)
19. renuncia: [**Hohmannfan** de Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/space-se-moderator-status)
20. resigned: [**Mego** de Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18240/its-time-for-me-to-leave), con la petición de eliminar todo su contenido de la red

Adicionalmente, otros han tomado otras acciones:

1. actividad suspendida: [**Paul White** de Database Administrators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-stealing-content-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooperat#comment1090605_333965)
2. actividad suspendida: [**James** de Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7514/627)
3. actividad suspendida: [**HDE 226868** de Worldbuilding, Astronomy, History of Science & Mathematics, y Mythology & Folklore](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7513/627)
4. <s>actividad suspendida: [**Rand al'Thor** de Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334060/134300)</s> Volvió a moderar el 31 de Octubre
5. actividad suspendida: [**fedorqui** de Spanish Language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334062/351483)
6. <s>actividad suspendida: [**Null** de Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334091/278659)</s> Volvió a moderar el 31 de Octubre
7. actividad suspendida antes de que acabasen las nuevas eleciones: [**Tensibai** de DevOps](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/7130)
8. tomó un descanso: [**ColleenV** de English Language Learners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-slippery-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested#comment1090769_333992)
9. actividad suspendida: [**Rory Alsop** / **Doktor Mayhem** de Information Security, Music, Parenting, The Great Outdoors, Sound Design, y Video Production](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334095/154443)
10. actividad suspendida: [**terdon** de Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, y Bioinformatics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334100/203101)
11. actividad suspendida: [**anongoodnurse** de Parenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334116/154443)
12. actividad no crítica suspendida: [**AviD** de Information Security](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334122/1185)
13. actividad no urgente suspendida: [**Anton Menshov** de Computational Science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334123/1185)
14. <s>actividad no urgente suspendida: [**Thomas Owens** de Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/334149#334149)</s>  Volvió a moderar el 12 de Octubre.
15. actividad suspendida: [**Kevin** de Science Fiction & Fantasy y The Great Outdoors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334177/172958)
    **(sólo queda un moderador activo en The Great Outdoors <s>y Science Fiction & Fantasy</s>)**
16. tomando un permiso de ausencia: [**Cyn** de Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/taking-a-personal-leave-of-absence)
    **(no quedan moderadores activos en Writing)**
17. actividad suspendida: [**Xander** de Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/334122#comment1093028_333965)
    **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Beer, Wine & Spirits)**
18. actividad suspendida / resignando pronto: [**Mad Scientist** de Skeptics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334305/1185)
19. actividad suspendida: [**jonsca** de Web Applications y Chemistry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334318/448600)
20. <s>actividad suspendida: [**Hohmannfan** de Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/space-se-moderator-status)</s> **renuncia**
21. actividad suspendida: [**nicoguaro** de Computational Science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper#comment1093653_334123)

    **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Computational Science)**
22. actividad suspendida: [**lois6b** de Stack Overflow en español](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334348/368819)
23. actividad suspendida: [**eykanal** de Academia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334390/139256)
24. actividad no crítica suspendida: **AJ Henderson** de Photography, Video Production, Sound Design and Community Building. Mismo razonamiento que [**Rory Alsop** / **Doktor Mayhem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334095/154443) 
    **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Sound SE y Video SE)**
25. actividad suspendida: [**Michael Hampton** de Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335013/189912)
26. actividad suspendida: [**Sven** de Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335297/)
27. se mantiene alejado de las colas de revisión y actividad reducida [Bhargav Rao on Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47581028#47581028)
28. actividad suspendida [**David** de Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/2217)
29. actividad suspendida [**Duarte Farrajota Ramos** de Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/2217)
30. actividad suspendida [**gandalf3** de Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/2217)
31. actividad suspendida [**iKlsR** de Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/2217)
    **(Los cuatro moderadores de [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators))**
32. actividad suspendida [**gung** de Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5779/7290)
33. actividad suspendida [**Hatchet** de Language Learning](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662/3081)

También relacionados con el incidente pero por otros motivos:

1. renuncia: [**Aza** de Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/resignation-notice), vale la pena leerlo, precede a muchos de los eventos. Mas tarde escribió una [actualización](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334750/162102) que vale más la pena leerla.
2. <s>renuncia: [**Journeyman Geek** *único* de Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333975/398063)</s>, sigue siendo moderador de Super User ([después pidió ser reinstaurado bajo los nuevos estatutos](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8015746#8015746))
3. renuncia: [**Keelan** de Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5067/32367)
4. renuncia: [**PashaPash** de Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9559/300888)
5. renuncia: [**rolfl** de Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/it-is-with-disappointment-that-i-hereby-resign-as-a-moderator)
6. renuncia: [**Tensibai** de DevOps](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/time-to-step-down-and-let-this-be)
7. renuncia: [**Jack Douglas** de Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3263)
   **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Database Administrators)**
8. actividad suspendida: [**Diego** de Spanish Language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334127/134300)
   **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Spanish Language)**
9. renuncia: [**George Stocker** de Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390427/im-resigning-as-a-stack-overflow-comunity-elected-moderator)  (mas tarde publicó lo que [SE debería hacer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390495/8239061) para resolver la situación actual)
10. renuncia: [**Sklivvz** de Skeptics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334307/1185)
11. renuncia: [**user58** de Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/i-no-longer-feel-safe-moderating-this-site) **(sólo queda un moderador activo en Literature)**
12. renuncia: [**Jon Clements** de Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390525/yet-another-step-down-as-moderator-post)

Finalmente, algunos moderadores y proyectos comunitarios han escrito comentarios o han tomado medidas como resultado de la situación:

1. decepcionado: [**StrongBad** de Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/stack-exchange-support-of-the-community) y [Expats](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/stack-exchange-support-of-the-community)
2. apoyo declarado a Monica: [**Cyn** / Writing mod team](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/se-has-removed-a-moderator)
3. SOBotics [deja de hacer Reportes](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47459757#47459757) junto con [Rodgort y Higgs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=47482178#47482178)
4. decepcionado: [**called2voyage** de Space Exploration y Astronomy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334289)
5. a punto de terminar: [**J.R.** de English Language Learners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334340/allow-monica-to-have-a-structured-conversation-%c3%a0-la-mediation-with-se-leadersh/334342#comment1093893_334342)
6. decepcionado: [**El'endia Starman**, **Peter Turner**, y **Mason Wheeler** de Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/we-are-not-resigning-yet)
7. decepcionado: [**Snow** de The Workplace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333968/351483)
8. Anunció soporte para Monica y para de participar en TL: [**yagmoth555** de Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9571/256639)
9. decepcionado: [**Mister Positive** de The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/61096/mister-positive)
10. decepcionados: [**Ganesh Sittampalam** y **JoeTaxpayer** de Personal Finance & Money](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/disappointed-in-stackexchange-management)

### Compañía *y* Comunidad

Entiendo que la compañía Stack Exchange esta bajo mucho estrés ahora mismo. Están en transición a un [nuevo presidente](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/) y de alguna manera necesitan llegar a ser rentables, lo cual podría ser la razón para las [extrañas proclamas sobre política de anuncios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333588/are-interstitial-ads-video-ads-and-autoplay-audio-ads-coming-to-se) o [promocionar agresivamente](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-an-official-sponsor-for-software-engineering) el producto Stack Overflow Teams en todas partes. Pero el estrés no es excusa para empezar una guerra con la base de usuarios.

Stack Exchange no es solo una comunidad pero también es una comunidad. Aunque la compañía proporciona la plataforma, la comunidad proporciona el contenido que hace valiosa la plataforma. Ambas partes pueden tener éxito solo colaborando una con la otra. Pero ahora mismo, parece que Stack Exchange Inc. ha renunciado a comunicarse con la comunidad y está tomando una actitud enconada.

**¿Está Stack Exchange Inc. todavía interesada en cooperar con la comunidad? ¿Cual es la visión para esta relación?**

- Si Stack Exchange quisiera empezar a relacionarse con la comunidad otra vez, los incidentes anteriores serían probablemente no más que unos lamentables errores. ¿Cómo prevendrá Stack Exchange que continúe esta ristra de errores en el futuro? ¿Qué hará Stack Exchange para solventar estos problemas?
- Si Stack Exchange quiere continuar por este camino hacia un rol de jefazo inflexible, la comunidad probablemente seguirá sangrando miembros a ritmos crecientes. ¿Cómo asegurará Stack Exchange que continue la alta calidad de los sitios de la red? Limitarse a intentar crecer más rápido solo exacerbará el problema.

Y por mi parte podéis esperar que pare de escribir respuestas o de participar de ninguna otra forma hasta que vea actos de buena fe encaminados a arreglar esta ruptura.

---

**2019-09-29:** 1a respuesta oficial — [Respuesta en la resignación de Monica](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel/5197#5197) ([copiado](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites/389908#389908) [en otra parte](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/i-am-resigning-as-a-moderator/1654#1654))

**2019-10-03:** 2a respuesta oficial — [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/145951). (puntuación **-2k** (+100 / -2,1k votos)

**2019-10-05:** Cronología de la situación de Mónica - [Como una publicación de blog](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2064709.html)

**2019-10-06:** 3a respuesta oficial — [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/229223)

**2019-10-06:** Cartas abiertas de moderadores — [Dear Stack Exchange: a statement and a letter from your moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334575/176034), y [La segunda carta aborda más específicamente los problemas que la comunidad LGBT+ considera que es necesario abordar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334577/377987)

**2019-10-10:** [Official FAQ on gender pronouns and Code of Conduct changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) (ahora eliminada con puntuación neta -1930 (+449 / -2379), [versión archivada](https://web.archive.org/web/20191023011602/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes))

**2019-10-15:** [Shog9, miembro del equipo de CMs, comenta sobre el trabajo del proceso de eliminación y restablecimiento de moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away/335607#335607)

**2019-10-18:** [Actualización de estado del Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335868/102937)

**2019-10-21:** [Proceso de eliminación y advertencia del moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators), [Proceso de Restablecimiento de Moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator).
**2019-10-21:** [Publicación de **respuestas** sobre los procesos de los Moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes)

**2019-10-22:** [FAQ de los nuevos pronombres](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns)

**2019-10-22:** [Post de **Seguimiento** de los FAQ de los nuevos pronombres](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq)

**2019-10-24:** Monica publica una respuesta de la situación — [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)

**2019-10-28** Monica prepara una página GoFundMe para ayudar económicamente a combatir este asunto. [Defender a Monica de la Difamación de Stack Overflow](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users)

**2019-10-31** Monica discutiendo la circunstancia en una entrevista de audio. [TTP #1 | Monica Cellio On The Fallout At Stack Exchange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Gracias Jose Antonio por informar a la comunidad sobre este debate. Sugiero a todos estar pendiente de esto, pues está desencadenando un montón de dimisiones por parte de moderadores tan sobresalientes como [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/19853), [Gilles](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650/110108) o [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389906/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui ...o tu mismo, pasando a estar inactivo como moderador de Spanish.SE

Comment: Han dimitido 15 moderadores, otros tantos están en "huelga" y la gente está debatiendo en posts, comentarios y chats sobre el tema, aún así SO sigue sin dar explicaciones de ningún tipo salvo: *hacemos lo que hay que hacer y es lo mejor para todos*. Pues ya están tardando y cada minuto que pasa sin que esto se resuelva es un minuto perdido para su reputación y un minuto más de cabreo para muchos usuarios. Yo ya me estoy planteando si quiero continuar participando en el sitio, todavía es solo una idea que me ronda pero no tardará en tomar forma.

Comment: Para mi han perdido un 99% de su credibilidad como empresa. Llevo unos dias siguiendolo de cerca y da mucha verguenza la manera en como StackOverflow esta gestionando la situacion independientemente del detonante. hay *trabajadaores* que estoy convencido que merecen la pena y trabajan duro y con unos valores muy distintos (como nuestro querido Juan) pero como empresa SO para mi... *garbage*.

Comment: Es el silencio sepulcral de la empresa ante la oleada de dimisiones y protestas de moderadores y usuarios, más que la causa de dichas protestas, lo que me tiene realmente perplejo. ¿NADIE en Stack tiene nada que decir al respecto? ¿El nuevo CEO, hola?

Comment: @Konamiman Creí que seguías trabajando para _La Compañía_. Saludos.

Comment: Ojalá, pero fui una víctima de la "masacre" del 2 de noviembre de 2017 :'(

Comment: @PaulVargas [What happened with the Stack Overflow layoffs (11/2017)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303005/what-happened-with-the-stack-overflow-layoffs-11-2017). [Developer community Stack Overflow reportedly lays off 20% as it refocusses business](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/02/stack-overflow-lays-off-staff/). [Twitter de un despedido](https://twitter.com/AndrewBrobston/status/926141946015420416). Lástima, 80000$ anuales es algo que difícilmente se va a poder cobrar en Baleares como desarrollador.

Comment: @Konamiman viendo la [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/346768) de la empresa, creo que era mejor no haber dicho nada. _Si lo que vas a decir, no es mas bello que el silencio..._ :)

Comment: @Pikoh Si los doctores en medicina hiciesen eso sus pacientes se morirían. Los problemas no son bellos, pero el silencio no siempre es la solución.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Por supuesto, totalmente de acuerdo.Tal vez no haya dejado clara la naturaleza irónica de mi comentario. Lo que quería decir es que es inaceptable el silencio de la empresa durante una semana, pero tal vez era mejor que un comunicado mas inaceptable en mi opinión.

Comment: Por cierto, @lois6b [acaba de posicionarse como inactivo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334348/346768) .

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuranOlmos Por eso no te preocupes. Ahora trabajo en Toptal, otra empresa usamericana; y aunque el sueldo es algo inferior al que tenía en Stack sigue siendo mucho mayor que el que podría  conseguir en cualquier empresa española, diría incluso que europea :-)

Comment: @Marc tremendo trabajo de sincronización de la publicación original con esta. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui Hay que mantener a todo el mundo informado de lo que esta pasando, un placer :)

Comment: Y entonces, ¿nada pasa con ésto?

Comment: Lo primero de todo, muchas gracias por la traducción @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, gran trabajo. He intentado seguir el hilo leyéndome varios de los posts que están linkeados (no tengo tiempo para leerme todos ya que estaba bastante desconectado del tema y me acabo de enterar gracias a este post). Hay dos cosas que no me han quedado claras e igual alguno que esteis más puestos en el meta me sabéis contestar... ¿se sabe a ciencia cierta que pasó con Monica? Por lo que he podido leer no se sabe nada a ciencia cierta. Y segundo, me he leido el post del cambio de política, ¿que implicaciones tiene?

Comment: Me refiero, la nueva política he visto que incluye cambios en los temas legales de propiedad pero no me queda del todo claro el alcance que tiene, es decir, en que aspectos afecta negativamente a la comunidad, la verdad es que de aspectos legales entiendo poco y me gustaría saber a que se debe tanto revuelo. Y por último, @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, ¿a que se refiere en la pregunta con preguntas "de copiar y pegar"? Me he metido en el link relacionado pero aparece una pregunta en la que se hace un hilo de memes de la comunidad SE por lo que no veo referencia entre una cosa y la otra.

Comment: Mónica ya ha recibido casi diez mil dólares en donaciones para ayudarle en los costes legales. Si SO no se baja del burro esto acaba en juicio.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Respuesta de copiar y pegar es la típica de llamar a soporte porque no funciona un programa y te dicen "¿Ha probado a reiniciar el ordenador?". En este caso se refiere a disculpas genéricas que lo mismo valdrían para este caso que para otros mil y que no entran en el fondo del asunto.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Osea si no he entendido mal... ¿¿la acusan de dar disculpas genéricas??

Comment: @FranciscoRomero El *tzunami* que derramó el vaso,  es que un representante de la Compañía le dijo a un reportero que la retiraron como moderadora ♦ por faltar reiteradamente al CoC a pesar de habérsele dado múltiples advertencias lo cual se llevó a cabo de manera muy desafortunada por  decir lo poco y algunas acciones posteriores de la Compañia como el pedir disculpas, primero una vez y luego otra para enmendar la primera no han sido bien recibidas.

Comment: @Rubén La verdad es que no veo tan grave (al menos a simple vista) como para que la echaran de todos los sitios. Tampoco entiendo porque Stackoverflow no da una respuesta clara de lo que pasó (con motivos concretos) pero supongo que si el resto de mods también se han ido será porque ven algo más allá de lo que se ve de momento a simple vista.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero En algún momento se argumentó que "por respeto a la privacidad..." lo cual es un ejemplo de "respuesta de copiar y pegar" al a que se hace mención en esta pregunta, sobre todo porque no respetaron la privacidad al hablar con un reportero. La verdad es que hay mucha gente involucrada y el agua está muy revuelta

Comment: @Rubén Veremos a ver que pasa y esperemos que todo se solucione. Yo la verdad que no me había enterado de nada hasta este post por lo que a partir de ahora intentaré estar un poco más atento de las novedades.

Comment: Leer Meta SE se volvió "leer a los abogados de SE". Triste.