# ¿En qué casos sería necesario hacer referencia a él/la autor(a) de una pregunta o respuesta en otra pregunta/respuesta en el sitio principal?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, código-de-conducta, respuesta

En las últimas semanas hay un tremendo revuelo en Meta SE y algunos sitios en inglés debido a diversas situaciones derivadas de un cambio en el código de conducta, en concreto, en lo relativo al uso de pronombres al referirnos a otro miembro de la comunidad.

En inglés

he/him, she/her, they/them

Si bien este cambio no se ha extendido a los sitios internacionales (aquellos cuyo idioma oficial no es el inglés), finalmente lo hará.

En español

él/le/lo/el, ella/le/la, ellos/les/los, ellas/les/las

Me queda claro que en los comentarios y en el chat habrá muchas ocasiones en las que habrá oportunidades de referirse a otro miembro de la comunidad lo que llevaría a usar algún pronombre pero considerando que los saludos, despedidas, firmas, lemas,  y en general cualquier texto que no sea necesario para hacer una pregunta o respuesta clara y completa se debe evitar, ¿en qué casos sería necesario hacer referencia a él/la autor(a) de una pregunta o respuesta en otra pregunta / respuesta del sitio principal?

Aclaración: No pretendo que en esta pregunta se discuta si se está de acuerdo o no con el cambio del Código de Conducta, ni de las formas de evitar el uso de los pronombres masculino/femenino, o el uso de masculino en los casos de género no marcado". Entiendo que algunas respuestas podrán mencionar esto, sólo espero que no sea el tema central de las mismas.

---

He buscado ejemplos de preguntas o respuestas en el sitio principal que usen "él" pero la mayoría de los resultados devuelven publicaciones con "el" sin acento.

En Meta tenemos varios casos que usan "él", por ejemplo publicaciones que hablan sobre Jon Skeet, los nuevos moderadores, entre otras.

Otra búsqueda ha sido `respuesta previa` pero aún no encuentro casos donde se use lo pronombres, pero si he encontrado casos donde se menciona al nombre del autor de otra publicación. A continuación algunos ejemplos de los hallazgos (las itálicas son mías)

> Añado información para completar la respuesta previa, *la de Jorgesys*, exactamente, añadiendo información sobre las SharedPreferences.

> Variante de la solución provista en la *respuesta de DjCrazi*, en lugar de usar dos fórmulas, se usa sólo una aprovechando la característica de uso de matrices en la hoja de cálculo de Google y la función `ArrayFormula`.

Nota: No coloco enlaces a la vista para tratar de atenuar el efecto meta negativo, sobre los ejemplos.

Relacionado

- [Echando mods y relicencia forzada, ¿está todavía Stack Exchange interesada en cooperar con la comunidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4364/65)
- [Durante un año "me he hecho pasar" por mujer en StackOverflow.es](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3807/65)
- [How should I refer to the OP?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318392/289691)

Comment: La verdad, no se si termino de entender tu pregunta Ruben. En cualquier caso, yo siempre uso _OP_ para referirme al autor de una pregunta, con lo que no veo necesario usar pronombres. Por otro lado, en español el masculino es el [genero no marcado](https://www.rae.es/consultas/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas) o inclusivo, por lo que no veo que la pólemica generada en los sitios cuyo idioma es el inglés nos afecte de ninguna manera.

Comment: Si afectase el CoC actual a sitios como SOes... Comentas que se deben evitar los pronombres pero... _“Use stated pronouns (when known).”_. Por lo que si el OP especifica su genero/pronombre sería "obligatorio" usarlo. [What does the CoC say about pronouns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns)

Comment: @x3k_js eso no sería exactamente así. Teóricamente, si alguien no usa pronombres de forma habitual en el sitio, puede omitir completamente los pronombres y estaría dentro del CoC. De todas maneras, creo que tratar este tema cuando por el momento no nos afecta no es necesario y puede provocar polémicas innecesarias.

Comment: ***¿en qué casos sería necesario hacer referencia a él/la autor(a) de una pregunta o respuesta en otra pregunta / respuesta del sitio principal?*** Yo tengo entendido lo siguiente: se hace referencia a la pregunta/respuesta, a menos que estemos en el caso de una traducción completa de la pregunta/respuesta donde también se menciona la autoría. Y cuando es el segundo caso, en particular se hace la referencia usando el alias. Yo en particular usaría *OP* o en todo caso *AP* para referirme a la autoría, y ambas siglas en mi criterio, cumplen el polémico CoC. Si no es así, me corrigen por favor.

Comment: Tampoco acabo de entender la pregunta: entiendo el título referido a atribución, pero luego mencionas pronombres en el cuerpo, para acabar volviendo a la atribución. ¿Podrías aclarar con casos concretos? Y que bueno que traigas el debate, porque -como dices- eventualmente también en los sitios no ingleses habrá que tratarlo.

Comment: @Pikoh La polémica es que las pautas tradicionales del idioma inglés dicen algo similar a lo que indica la RAE sin embargo el CoC dice otra cosa y eventualmente tendremos la misma situación acá, el CoC nos dirá que hagamos cosas diferentes a la lo que sugiere la RAE.

Comment: @x3k_js Yo no comento que se deben evitar los pronombres, al contrario, estoy preguntando en cuáles casos podrían usarse en el sitio priincipal.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿Dices "el OP" o "la OP"?

Comment: @fedorqui Como lo menciono en la edición que acabo he buscado "él". Mas tarde buscaré "el autor", "el OP", "el AP". ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo encontrar los casos concretos? ¿Cómo puedo realizar una búsqueda que sólo devuelva publicaciones con `él`?

Comment: @Pikoh En cuanto a polémicas innecesarias parte del drama en Meta SE es que algunos argumentan que introducir en el CoC el tema de los pronombres está causando polémicas innecesarias y lo que es peor aparentemente ha sido causa de la remoción de los privilegios de moderador diamantado de una persona lo que a vuelto muy complicada la situación. Me parece que abordar el tema con anticipación prevendrá situaciones así.

Comment: No es necesario ni siquiera saber el género del OP/AP. Al referirme al mismo por norma general escribo el alias. Por ejemplo si `@Rubén` ha escrito algo interesante, me refiero justamente así al mismo. *En esta pregunta/respuesta (link), escrita por `@Rubén`...*, u otro ejemplo: *En esta pregunta/respuesta, proporcionada por `@Rubén`...*, y aún más: *Se nota que la solución dada por el/la OP/AP en esta pregunta/respuesta (link)*. Formas hay muchas, y sólo usaría *él o la* cuando el alias indique claramente su uso, como por ejemplo: `@Rubén`. Saludos

Comment: @Rubén no me entiendas mal, meta está para discutir cualquier cosa que afecte al sitio y me parece totalmente legitimo que lo traigas aqui. Lo que creo es que el idioma inglés es fundamentalmente diferente en lo que respecta a los pronombres al español, y que considero que el genero masculino es inclusivo para hombres, mujeres, transexuales y cualquier otro género.

Comment: Estamos poco acostumbrados a algo que parece ser tendencia en el lenguaje, (que en mi opinión no tiene pies ni cabeza). Errores vamos a cometer, como podrán ver en mi edición del comentario. Y es que en cuestiones de lenguaje no existe ni existirá una autoridad inquisidora, ya que como he aprendido, el lenguaje es un ente vivo, y cambia, se adapta y se transforma. Aprendí el castellano cuando el Latín aún era un idioma y las letras `ch` y `ll` existían en nuestro abecedario. Pero lo que no tolero son las imposiciones, pero eso es otro tema.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Me has dado buenas ideas para buscar casos concretos, de hecho me parece que yo mismo he hecho algo así, pero lo había olvidado por completo.

Comment: @fedorqui Que bueno que mencionas las atribuciones, definitivamente que en los casos en los que se tome contenido de alguien mas podría mencionarse a el(la) autor(a).

Answer (score 1):

Algunos casos en los que es menciona el nombre de usuario del autor que he identificado gracias a los comentarios (faltaría agregar más ejemplos reales)

1. Atribución de una idea, un caso o ejemplo al explicar las circunstancias

   - Fulano en su respuesta a `x` dice `y` pero él luego menciona en `z` que `j`
2. Menciones de un autor al hacer referencia al contenido de su publicación cuando se explica porqué una pregunta no es un duplicado

   - Esta pregunta no es un duplicado de la pregunta de fulana porque ella dijo `x` pero lo que yo busco es `y`
3. Menciones de un autor al hacer referencia al contenido de su publicación cuando se explica porqué se agrega una respuesta "tardía", complementaria, diferente a las respuestas anteriores.

   - fulano mencionó en su respuesta que la situación se debe a `x` pero él está asumiendo `y`, si ese no fuera tu caso, prueba `z`

Algunos casos en los que se menciona "el autor" (faltaría agregar mas casos )

- > **El autor** de la respuesta a Google Docs viewer returning 204 responses, no longer working, alternatives? comparte un "hack" / truco que consiste en refrescar el ifram cada 2 segundos hasta que se Google Doc Viewer cargue correctamente. El código compartido por **el autor** de la respuesta, implica el uso de jQuery, es el siguiente:

Comment: En los ejemplos que provees los pronombre "él" o "ella" se pueden omitir, esa es la belleza del castellano :-). En general en mis respuestas omito señalar el género/sexo y solo lo señalo como "el usuario X" o "@X"

Comment: @eyllanesc: Sí de acuerdo que en los tres primeros ejemplos él o ella se pueden omitir. En los ejemplos que he puesto en la pregunta no usan el/la él/ella. Considero que la recomendación de omitirlo o los consejos sobre como evitar usarlos sería mejor tratarlo en otra pregunta.

Comment: @eyllanesc, coincido contigo en que el pronombre se puede omitir, sin embargo dices: ***solo lo señalo como "el usuario X"*** a lo que alguien podría preguntarte: ¿Y porqué no ***la usuaria X***? Asumiendo que el alias no es indicativo de género, como `@eyllanesc`. La pregunta que harán es ¿porqué usar un género masculino para generalizar? Y allí es donde se presenta la polémica que a causado el susodicho CoC, porque lo estarías violando.

Comment: @MauricioContreras me parece muy rebuscado hacer ello, para mi indicar "el usuario" implica "cualquier persona que usa algo" por lo que para mi la abstraigo del género. Entonces si vamos a estar con esas nimiedades es mejor usar `@X` o buscar un adjetivo que no tenga género como por ejemplo "La persona X", etc, o usar ambos casos "el/la usuario(a)"

Comment: Nuevamente de acuerdo contigo @eyllanesc, y es precisamente el punto polémico del CoC. Desde un punto de vista conservador, en castellano se generaliza con el pronombre masculino **el**. Sin embargo, lo que tu llamas *nimiedades* es precisamente lo que el CoC pretende implementar. En la actualidad existe una comunidad que lucha por erradicar lo que consideran *falocentrismo*, del lenguaje. Hay quienes no se identifican ni con el pronombre *el* y tampoco con el pronombre *la*. Y asumir uno u otro deja por fuera o *excluye*, según el CoC, precisamente a un grupo de dicha comunidad. Así estamos.

Comment: @eyllanesc el hacer virguerías y peripecias en la redacción para esquivar usar un pronombre concreto además de costoso a nivel personal (tienes que pensar más de dos veces antes de publicar) mueve la carga del esfuerzo del lector al autor; eso es un disparate. Si una persona se siente mal por un pronombre mal usado no tiene más que decirlo y se arregla, no podemos pretender que todo el mundo vaya con pies de plomo escribiendo para resolver un problema que ni siquiera es un problema.