# ¿Esta permitido utilizar el "lenguaje inclusivo" como respuesta y pregunta en este sitio?

Tags: discusión, código-de-conducta

Desde siempre internet se maneja con neutralidad sin apegos politicos ni religiosos, etc. Pero últimamente he visto un par de comentarios con la letra `x` o modismos con `e`. Lo cual me deja preguntándome si está bien que se permita esto. Saber la posición del sitio me es importante para entender si aquí se respeta la neutralidad o no. Si no fuese asi, eso significaría que estaría en riesgo de ofender a alguien si es que yo, no hablase de esa forma (algo que no quiero); ya que no he podido encontrar informacion oficial temo que podrían sancionarme o algo parecido...

Comment: Este sitio es sobre programación, no sobre *lenguaje inclusivo*

Comment: Ni permitido, ni prohibido, por ahora al menos y espero que nunca, nadie te va sancionar de ninguna forma, por escribir de tal cual manera.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho [esto...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334417/209901)

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', recordaba que se había habido bastante revuelo con este tema hace un tiempo atrás, pero no encontraba nada escrito. Ahora una pregunta que no quiero hacer y compete a los que solemos hacer correcciones ortográficas ¿Es correcto tratar los términos en lenguaje "inclusivo" como errores ortográficos?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es una pregunta compleja. Yo no tocaría nada de lo escrito así, a menos que simplemente sobre. Si alguien por ejemplo empieza una publicación con un "hola a todos y todas", pues la cuestión no es cambiar por "hola a todos", sino directamente quitarlo porque es ruido. No sé si pensabas en algún caso concreto.

Comment: Acá en Argentina es bastante corriente el uso de "Todes",  "chiques", "niñes", "les" por "los" y cosas por el estilo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho a mí no me parece mal, que cada cual escriba como quiera siempre que no hiera a nadie.

Comment: Es cierto que en el contexto de una pregunta sobre programación, es raro ver que se necesite usar el lenguaje inclusivo y si bien estoy muy tentado a considerarlo como un error ortográfico (que creo que lo es) entiendo que deberíamos privilegiar la convivencia en paz.

Comment: Mi única consideración más general, es que el grado de uso de lenguaje inclusivo entiendo, puede ser muy dispar entre los países hispanohablantes y lo que puede ser claro para alguno podría llegar a ser inentendible para otro. Pero bueno, no voy a seguir desviando el tema de la pregunta, en algún momento imagino, surgirá la necesidad de consensuar estos temas.

Comment: Si alguien se ofende porque un desconocido escribe de una manera que no le gusta, el problema es de quien se ofende, no de quien escribe.

Comment: El idioma español no es machista y  hay que hablarlo correctamente no veo nada bien que se use todes en vez de todos o todas. A Vargas Llosa una vez le preguntaron sobre el tema y dijo que es una ridiculez maltratar de esa forma el idioma, yo concuerdo con el

Comment: [Relacionado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4400/65)

Comment: El lenguaje no es exclusivo ni mucho menos, son las personas y ciertos grupos de la sociedad que les gusta complejizarse y politazan todo, al final es una cuestión de acomplejamiento

Comment: @PatricioMoracho habla por vos, la cantidad que lo usen en algunos lugares no lo hace común, ni mucho menos aceptable.

Comment: @tincopasan ¿y qué es aceptable? Al fin y al cabo, una convención que varía con el tiempo. Sin *jugar* con el lenguaje, este no evoluciona. ¿Qué dirías de alguien que dice "crocodilo" o escribe "hacera" o "facera" en lugar de "acera"? Pues contrariamente a lo que parece, era lo "correcto" antes. Los hablantes utilizaron otras variantes y acabó usándose la actual. En nuestro mundo: si todo el mundo usara PHP no querría decir que usar Python fuera inaceptable, sino que las modas irían por allí.

Comment: @ticopasan, sin duda hablo por mi, por eso es una opinión. En Argentina el uso diría que es muy común y habitual, además de que existen iniciativas oficiales que han incorporado el lenguaje inclusivo a documentos oficiales, tanto en la justicia, gobierno y universidades. Yo lo sigo considerando un horror de la lengua, pero aprendí a aceptarlo por que para mucha gente es importante.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster totalmente de acuerdo, no me ofende para nada que se escriba así ¿pero si edito la pregunta es correcto corregirlo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. No hay ninguna regla que te obligue a escribir con una e, una @, una x o lo que se les ocurra mañana.

Lo que si se pide, es que si alguien prefiere que te dirijas a su persona de determinada manera, respetes eso y lo hagas como esa persona lo prefiere. No importa si es él, ella o elles... Hay que tratar de respetar sus deseos.

Ahora, nadie te va a sancionar si cometes un error honesto. Si alguien tiene una foto de un hombre, y mas allá de su apodo en el sitio te referís a esa persona como él, y esa persona, sin decirlo claramente, quería ser tratado de ella, se considera que tu error no es a propósito y no va a pasar nada.

Lo que si podría llevar a acarrear alguna sanción, es referirse a alguien de una forma que no sea respetuosa. Si alguien pide que lo llames de alguna forma, de forma bien explicita (no alcanza con ponerlo en su bio) entonces si deberías tratar en lo sucesivo (si estas teniendo por ejemplo un intercambio en comentarios) de llamarlo como esa persona lo pidió. Sin embargo, no debes llevar ni un recuento ni es necesario que te acuerdes de todas las formas en que las personas quieren ser llamadas.

Lo que se pide, es honestidad en la forma de referirse a otras personas.

Comment: Creo que esta de más la explicación. Es internet. Si quieres que te llamen de algúna manera ponlo en tu nombre de usuario. Nunca vamos a saber si eres hombre, mujer, no binario, etc. Diferente es que te pidan usar gramática incorrecta. Me he peleado con muchos de ustedes por que me corrigen al usar la gramática mal (el modo al principio fue duro) y ahora que me he resignado a aprender mi lengua nativa me van a decir que "todes" estaban equivocados? Bastante incongruencia.

Comment: @Legna no termino de entender tu comentario... a que te referis con gramatica incorrecta? Lo que pedimos es solamente respeto.. no otra cosa....

Comment: En el contexto de la pregunta menciona, entre otros, modismos a utilizar con e. Eso es a la gramática.Por la parte de respetó, no hay nada que explicar, y la de aceptar, depende de que contexto. Aceptamos faltas ortográficas por qué si?

Comment: No las aceptamos porque si. Tampoco discriminamos si alguien escribe con faltas ortograficas. Si se ha pedido en algunas publicaciones, que al menos se entendieran..

Comment: entonces preguntarle a alguien si es GAY no es Sancionable??? por que la misma Comunidad LGTBYXZ cuando se utiliza el nombre de su orientación sexual se sienten ofendidos ... como si fuera un insulto o algo malo ser GAY por ejemplo...